# Live Corner Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud, corners

Is there a way to restore live corners in a shape? For example when I expand a text or object, sometimes the symbol of dynamic corner doesn't appear.

Answer (score 1):

The corner widget has a hard limit of 100 handles of the current selection. When you expand your text, if it generates more than 100 handles, the corner widgets will not appear. You can select a few letters at a time and it should work as normal, so long as the number of selected handles does not exceed 100.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to live corners.

In that case you just need to go under the `View` menu and down to `Hide/Show Corner Widget`

[image]

I would also recommend checking out [Adobe's site on the topic](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/reshape-with-live-corners.html)